# DbDomainService<T> does not generate proxy entities

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ria, code-first

I have tried this on both visual studio 2010 and 11 beta, on several machines. I have also used EF 4.3 and 5.0 - beta 2. I am trying a code first approach in silverlight 5.

I create a DbDomainService and also create CRUD operations for it, but on the client side no proxy entities are being created. I am doing this in a WCF Class Library. Here is how it is created: I add a project to the solution (WCF RIA Services class library). A client side and service side project are added automatically and linked via RIA link. I create my entities and dbcontext (see source below). I create my domain service class (the wizard only shows up half the time, very buggy as well) and make sure there are CRUD operations. I rebuild, and show all files on the client side project and there is NO GENERATED CODE. If I change the DomianService class to inherit from DomainService instead of DbDomainService, then my proxy entities generate on the client side as expected.

I get the following warning when building the solution:

Warning 1 The following exception occurred creating the MEF composition container:
 Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
 The default code generator will be used. AProgram.Client.RIAServices

PLEASE HELP :)

```
    namespace AProgram.Server.RIAServices.Models.Sales
    {

       public class Customer
       {
          [Key]
          public int CustomerID { get; set; }

          [Required]
          [MaxLength(50)]
          public string CustomerName { get; set; }
       }

    }

    namespace AProgram.Server.RIAServices
    {
       public class SalesDbContext : DbContext
       {
          public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
       }
    }

    namespace AProgram.Server.RIAServices
    {
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.ComponentModel;
       using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
   using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;


   // TODO: Create methods containing your application logic.
   [EnableClientAccess()]
   public class SalesDomainService : DbDomainService<SalesDbContext>
   {
      [Query(IsComposible=false)]
      public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
      {
         return this.DbContext.Customers.Find(id);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an answer for anyone that is curious. It seems that Ria Services is only compatible with EF 4.1. I found a workaround in a code project article:

```
<runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" 
           publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
       </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```

Simply add this to your Web.config file, or if using a Ria Services Class Library, add it to the app.config and rename the app.config to web.config.

Here is a link to the article: [Code project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354715/Creating-a-WCF-RIA-Services-Class-Library-for-a-Si)

Comment: I think that I could waste *DAYS* against this issue, but your post saved me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into problems with RIA and EF as well, and the cure for me was to use the NuGetPackage [RIAServices.EntityFramework](http://nuget.org/packages/RIAServices.EntityFramework/4.1.60730.0). The problem is, that RIA services only support certain versions of EF. At the moment, it looks like it only supports <= 4.1.

Comment: Lame. There have been 4 releases since 4.1 and they didn't update RIA? Boggle. Looks like  I will be using a normal domain service and creating my own DbContext behind the scenes.